# Rotate an ellipse using arc method Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using context arc method i need to rotate an arc on the canvas.

```
ctx.save(); 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(cx-rx, cy-ry);
ctx.scale(rx, ry);
ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180); // angle = 45 will move away from the cordinates
ctx.arc(1, 1, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.restore(); 
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: You need the negative translation of  `ctx.translate(cx-rx, cy-ry);` after the `ctx.rotation`

Comment: I tried that didn't worked too